# select view in mobile devices like a dropdown not like a modal

Tags: html, css, angular

I have select elements, on mobile devices when I display them they appear as a modal with the options. However, what I require is to change that view from modal to the view that is observed on desktop devices, that is, in the form of a drop-down list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use native elements such as `select` it is the device that decides how to display it.
If you want to have a display like on a desktop but on a phone you have to simulate the behavior by creating the component yourself.
Or you can use a component library.

Comment: thanks for your answer